# ESPER: a pattern (CreatePattern) is not an special kind of epl sentence (CreateEPL)?

Tags: esper

I don't know which are the differences between a pattern  (CreatePattern) and a epl sentece (CreateEPL)
In the documentation appears as an example of CreatePattern

```
 EPStatement 10secRecurTrigger = admin.createPattern("every timer:at(*, *, *, *, *, */10)");
```

What is the difference with the next epl sentence?

```
select current_timestamp as field from pattern [every timer:interval(10 sec) ];
```

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent "select * from pattern[every timer:interval(10 sec)]" and "every timer:interval(10 sec)" (the latter via createPattern API call). The createPattern method invokes the pattern compiler only.